# setting the gridview fore color by color name or color code using c#

Tags: c#, colors, telerik

I have a string containing whether the color name or the color code. So the string could contain e.g. `Blue` or `ff106603`. What I'm trying to do is to get the right color to set it as fore color in a `Telerik RadGridView`. I tried to use `Color.FromName(string name)` method, which works fine with the color name. But it doesn't work with the color code (logically). After some researches I tried to parse the string using `UInt32.TryParse()`. I have the following code now:

```
private void gvCustComments_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells["Color"].Value != null)
    {
        UInt32 res;
        string color = e.Row.Cells["Color"].Value.ToString().Substring(2);

        if (UInt32.TryParse(color, out res))
            e.CellElement.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb((int)res);

        else
            e.CellElement.ForeColor = Color.FromName(e.Row.Cells["Color"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have three rows in the grid view. First is a color code `ff106603`, second is `Red` and third is `Black`. Red and black are working fine. But I still have some problems with the color code. When I debug it the fore colors value is `0, 1, 160, 107`. This is the correct value, but in the grid view I cannot see the text. It seems the fore color is set to transparent, instead of dark green.

I'm using C#, Telerik, WinForms and .NET Framework 4.5.2. Any ideas?

Comment: One does not simply use if statements without curly brackets!

Comment: matter of taste :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ColorConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colorconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Usage would be something like this:

```
ColorConverter colorConverter = new ColorConverter();
var colorFromHexCode = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ff106603");
var colorFromName = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString("Blue");
Console.WriteLine(colorFromHexCode.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(colorFromName.ToString());
```

The output is:

```
Color [A=255, R=16, G=102, B=3]
Color [Blue]
```

It won't convert hex values unless it starts with "#".

Answer (score 0):

To convert color you can use unchecked().

```
<asp:Label ID="here" runat="server" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh">
```

and

```
int trouut = unchecked((int)0Xff106603); 
here.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(trouut);
```

I hope it will help.

regards, 
Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Color Name separate rows. Usage would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; (i <= (DGview.Rows.Count - 1)); i++)
{ 
    DGview.Rows(i).Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```